# error: class "" has no member named ""? Is a solution to this specific case possible?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, member-functions

I know that this is probably a pointless question because it is obvious that class `BASE` does not have a function called `pass_A`, it is actually declared in another class called `A` and I though that using inheritance and polymorphism would allow the `BASE` class to see itself and the object of type `A`. I definitely want an object of type `A` to be able to call the class `A` from within `BASE` as well as `BASE` being declared the way it is now in `init_BASE`. My ultimate question is is this possible? Maybe I'm not using virtuals or something else is wrong.

**What I want is for the object `POLY_TYPE` to be able to contain both `BASE` and `A` class types.** 
Anyways heres the error message and the code below it.

**EDITED**  Look at solution instead.

Comment: Shift keys everywhere are weeping.

Comment: pass_A would need to be a virtual function, also declared in base, to be seen via a base ptr

Comment: A smaller example would have been welcome. Replacing `BASE*` with `int` would have made this far more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's all you need to do, then just don't discard type information until you absolutely must:

```
A<T>* a = new A<T>;
a->pass_A(new NODE);
POLY_TYPE = a;
```

Edit:

You didn't post any error message on your update - funny how so many people who ask questions here believe that the actual error is irrelevant - but you also have a type problem.
Since you pass a `NODE*` to pass_A, the template parameter must be `NODE*`, not `NODE`.

The following compiles (cleanup of the version with no virtuals, with my tweak):

```
class NODE
{
public:
    NODE(){}
    ~NODE(){}
    NODE&  operator=(const NODE&) { return *this; }
};

template <class T>
class A;

template <class T>
class BASE
{    
public:
    BASE(){}
    BASE(int mode)
    {
        if(mode == 1)
        {
            init_BASE();
        }
        else if(mode == 0)
        {
            init_A();
        }
    }
private:
    void init_BASE()
    {
        POLY_TYPE = new BASE<T>;
    }

    void init_A()
    {
        A<T>* a = new A<T>;
        a->pass_A(new NODE);
        POLY_TYPE = a;
    }

    BASE* POLY_TYPE;
};

template <class T>
class A : public BASE<T>
{
public:
    void pass_A(T DATA)
    {
        this->DATA = DATA;
    }
private:
    T DATA;
};

int main()
{
    BASE<NODE*> base(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope this line `a->pass_A(new NODE);` is still not working if I edit my second post with the virtuals. Do you mean the first post I had?

Answer (score 4):

Compiler is telling you the truth - `BASE` indeed does not have a member called `pass_A`.

Here `POLY_TYPE->pass_A(new NODE());` you're trying to call `pass_A` through a pointer to `BASE`. Compiler will look up the method based on the static type of the object (that is, `BASE` as opposed to dynamic type, which is `A` - why all the caps, btw?).

You'll need to add a `virtual pass_A` method to the base class if you want this work.

<sub>(I'm intentionaly leaving out the fact that BASE is a template - the type is really `BASE<T>` where T is whatever type you instantiate the template with. It is not directly related to the problem)</sub>

Comment: I use all caps for class names to distinguish them from normal variables. It just it makes them standout, I'm not really yelling. So I just put a `virtual pass_A` in the `BASE` class and leave the `pass_A` as is in the `A` class?

Comment: @lost_with_coding If you would be using uppercase for class (or type) names only, at least you had some consistency - but you ruin this too when you create `BASE * POLY_TYPE`; and to increase confusion exponentially you even call this pointer a type. I'd bet some bucks on that you won't be able to maintain that in 3 months

Comment: @lost_with_coding I didn't say you're yelling :) All caps are conventionaly used in C++ for macros, so your style is unusual, to say the least. And yes, put `virtual pass_A` in base class (optionaly pure virtual). It needs to have the same signature, as the one in derived class.

Comment: Alright guys I'll change my style, I just thought it looked useful anyways please see my edit in my post I still can't run this thing, thanks so far.

Comment: @lost_with_coding Your code from update doesn't compile because you're trying to instantiate an abstract class (in `main`).

Comment: @jrok So I can't use the class at all now?

Comment: Remove the `=0` from the definition of `pass_A`. That makes the function pure virtual and these in turn make the class abstract.

Comment: Ok I did that but then the same problem comes back with this line `POLY_TYPE->pass_A(new NODE());`?

Comment: That's because you're passing a pointer `(new NODE())` but the functions expect a `NODE`. Dude/dudette, read the error messages and do some reading on polymorphism, I can't debug your code like this for you :)